# ¿How to do an Angularjs filter combination?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this fragment object:

```
[{id: 721, titulo: "Cotizador Gastos Médicos Bx+ 2019", descripcion: "Cotizador Gastos Médicos Bx+ Tarifas 2019", updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:30:22.0", idCategoria: "1", …},
{id: 88, titulo: "Cotizador GMM Colectivo", descripcion: "Cotizador GMM Colectivo", updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:27:43.0", idCategoria: "1", …},
{id: 302, titulo: "Cotizador AP Escolar", descripcion: "Cotizador Accidentes Personales Escolar", updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:26:48.0", idCategoria: "1", …},
{id: 865, titulo: "Cotizador Únikuz Bx+", descripcion: "Cotizador Únikuz Bx+", updateDate: "2020-03-19 13:14:01.0", idCategoria: "1", …},
{id: 381, titulo: "Cotizador Premia Bx+", descripcion: "Cotizador Premia Bx+", updateDate: "2020-01-02 12:27:43.0", idCategoria: "1", …},
{id: 89, titulo: "Cotizador Vida Grupo", descripcion: "Cotizador Vida Grupo", updateDate: "2019-12-26 17:20:00.0", idCategoria: "1", …}]
```

That works well because It search on my elements (If I search "GMM COLECTIVO" result is ok):

[GMM COLECTIVO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2kv2.png)

But if i try to search "COLECTIVO GMM" it doesnt found:

[COLECTIVO GMM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JliFQ.png)

Im using this JS códe:

```
getData: function () {
            return $filter('filter')(this.data, this.filter);
        },
```

My view:

```
<div>
    <input class="input-buscar" id="pagFormatosfilter" type="text"
        ng-model="pagFormatos.filter" min="3"
        placeholder="Escriba texto a buscar"
        ng-change="pagFormatos.onUpdateFilter()"><br>
    <div ng-cloak
        style="text-align: right; font-size: larger; font-weight: bold;">
        <label>{{pagFormatos.label1()}}</label> <br>
    </div>

</div>
```

Whats the correct way to do this filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code with a filter using dynamically built regular expression.

Items will be filtered by `titulo`. The words in the query filter must at least contain 3 letters or will be ignored.

In order to appear, the `titulo` property must contain one of the words separated by a `|`.

```
(?<=^|\s)(Colectivo|GMM|Cotizador...)
```

`(?<=^|\s)` means a word is preceded either by the start of the query string or a space.

Words are not case sensitive because we use the regular expression pattern modifier `gi` where `i` means *case insensitive*.

[Play with the regex on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gfUocm/1)

**Sample code**

```js
angular.module("myApp", []);
angular
  .module("myApp")
  .controller("itemsController", [
    "$scope",
    "itemsService",
    function ($scope, itemsService) {
      $scope.items = itemsService.getItems();
      $scope.itemsFilter = function (item) {
        if ($scope.queryFilter && $scope.queryFilter.length) {
          var words = $scope.queryFilter.split(" ").filter(function (word) {
            return word.length >= 3; // Ignore words with less than 3 letters
          });
          var pattern = "(?<=^|\\s)(" + words.join("|") + ")";
          var re = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");
          return re.test(item.titulo);
        }
        return true;
      };
    },
  ])
  .service("itemsService", function () {
    return {
      getItems: function () {
        return [
          {
            id: 721,
            titulo: "Cotizador Gastos Médicos Bx+ 2019",
            descripcion: "Cotizador Gastos Médicos Bx+ Tarifas 2019",
            updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:30:22.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
          {
            id: 88,
            titulo: "Cotizador GMM Colectivo",
            descripcion: "Cotizador GMM Colectivo",
            updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:27:43.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
          {
            id: 302,
            titulo: "Cotizador AP Escolar",
            descripcion: "Cotizador Accidentes Personales Escolar",
            updateDate: "2020-03-25 14:26:48.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
          {
            id: 865,
            titulo: "Cotizador Únikuz Bx+",
            descripcion: "Cotizador Únikuz Bx+",
            updateDate: "2020-03-19 13:14:01.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
          {
            id: 381,
            titulo: "Cotizador Premia Bx+",
            descripcion: "Cotizador Premia Bx+",
            updateDate: "2020-01-02 12:27:43.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
          {
            id: 89,
            titulo: "Cotizador Vida Grupo",
            descripcion: "Cotizador Vida Grupo",
            updateDate: "2019-12-26 17:20:00.0",
            idCategoria: "1",
          },
        ];
      },
    };
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="itemsController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="queryFilter">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:itemsFilter">
      {{item.titulo}}
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also extract the code in a dedicated filter which will receive 2 params, the items collection and the query filter.

```
.filter("itemsFilter", function () {
    return function (items, queryFilter) {
      return items.filter(function (item) {
        if (queryFilter && queryFilter.length) {
          var words = queryFilter.split(" ").filter(function (word) {
            return word.length >= 3; // Ignore words with less than 3 letters
          });
          var pattern = "(?<=^|\\s)(" + words.join("|") + ")";
          var re = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");
          return re.test(item.titulo);
        }
        return true;
      });
    };
  })
```

Don't forget to pass the `queryFilter` as a parameter.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | itemsFilter:queryFilter">
    {{item.titulo}}
</div>
```

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7h0ew38g/1/) on JSFiddle

**Warning**

In both cases, the code filter is executed on client-side. If you have a lot of items, don't do this and pass query filter to your api to apply filter on server-side.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Janicaud you really help me, that works

Comment: Hey @Stephane Janicaud one question, for example on http://jsfiddle.net/7h0ew38g/1/ if i wirte "bx+ nikuz" my target is on 2nd row, how can i order by coincidences?, thank you